# Touchpad not working on ACER Aspire LT Model V3-471G with 16.04

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

Went through the past archives extensively to find a solution to this, none of them worked.  OS, Ubuntu 16.04.3 TLS, H/W ACER Aspire LT Model V3-471G, BIOS Version 1.18, processor i5-3210m, 2.5 GHz.  I'm not using an external mouse but want to use only the touchpad.  The installation went without a hitch, this is a brand new install, not an upgrade.  Everything is working, except the touchpad.

Tried various options provided in the past, such as installing synaptics, modifying the 90-synaptics.conf etc.  Nothing worked.  Installing synaptics makes it worse, the keyboard input stops working.  BIOS doesn't have any option to switch from advanced to basic touchpad either.

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                           id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                          id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]

$ uname -a
Linux roblox-Aspire-V3-471G 4.10.0-30-generic #34~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 2 02:14:26 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

$ xinput list-props 13
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (154):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (156): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.
000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (277): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (278):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (279):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (280):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (281):  112, 2688, 68, 1192
    Synaptics Finger (282): 1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (283):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (284):   135
    Synaptics Tap Durations (285):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (286):   0
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (287):  75
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (288):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (289):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (290): 61, 61
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (291): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (292):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (293): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.065147, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (294):    2
    Synaptics Locked Drags (295):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (296):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (297): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (298):   1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (299): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (300):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (301): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (302):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (303): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (304):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (305): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (306):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (307): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (308):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (309):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (310):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (311):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (312): 31, 31
    Synaptics Area (313):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (314): 15, 15
    Device Product ID (272):    2, 14
    Device Node (273):  "/dev/input/event7"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: And what is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: roblox@roblox-Aspire-V3-471G:~$ uname -a
Linux roblox-Aspire-V3-471G 4.10.0-30-generic #34~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 2 02:14:26 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: All looks OK. The touchpad should work. What does `xinput list-props 13` output?

Answer (score 1):

this is solved for now.  After booting, I just have to issue Fn+F7 to get the touchpad to work.  However, I need to do this after every reboot, the change is not persistent.  Oh well, I will live have to learn to live with this.  Thanks to all who offered various suggestions.

Comment: Check BIOS. Maybe device is disabled there.